# Which factors determine memory usage of a Javascript application?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, memory-management, browser

I have a Javascript application which on one device requires around 50 MB, but on another requires around 80 MB, measured as JS heap size. The annoying thing is that the first device is the more performant, and more resourceful in all aspects, so the memory usage is of less or no importance there. On the low-performing device, 80 MB is too much.

Which factors could contribute to occupying more memory on the low-performing device than on the high-performing? And what can be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

Are the CPU's the same down to the stepping? Older CPU's might be the real problem. In worst case they emulate float.

Are the version of the VM exactly the same? Older systems are often slower and have worse Garbage Collection. Older GC's might leak things that newer doesn't.

Are the OS the same, the underlaying memory manager might be the source of the problem.

Are the system settings the same, when does GC trigger. On some systems you can do a forceGC or schedule GC.

Setting the max heap lower is a double edged sword which can lead to crashes if you actually use more than you said you would.